# Bash return [: =: unexpected operator error

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I just do a simple task,input a bc then if c is "+" it will print total of a+b

So i do this

```
echo "$a $b $c = "

if [ $c = "+" ]; then
    echo $(($a + $b))
fi
```

And it return `simple.sh: 3: [: =: unexpected operator`

What is going on?? Please help, thank a lot, im so confuse now

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: OMG that site save my half life :') , thank you, try 3 nights to add two number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$c` is unset or set to nothing then the expression would expand to: `[ = + ]` which would cause this problem.

Always quote your parameter expansions as the result will be unexpected otherwise:

```
[ "$c" = "+" ]
```

Unquoted parameter expansions will undergo word splitting and pathname expansion.

Whenever writing shellscripts it always a good idea to use the shellcheck linter, an online version is available at https://www.shellcheck.net/